# how to change the font size and font family of multiple text of same class using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

i am designing a card in which there is multiple element in a div. I want to change the font size and font family from the dropdown when we click on the div using jquery. Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you through a bit your real code just to get idea how you want to implement

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.class-name').css({
    'font-family': 'your, font, family',
    'font-size': '16px'
});
```

Comment: i have the div like this<div class="card"><div id="name" class="drag_and_edit">name</div>
<div id="phone" class="drag_and_edit">phone</div>
<div id="address" class="drag_and_edit">address</div></div> and script $(".drag_and_edit").live('select',function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  getfontsize(id);
  return true;
 });  function getfontsize(id){
  $("#font-size").bind('change',function(){ 
      $("#"+id).css("font-size", $(this).val()+"px");
           }); 
  $("#font-family").one('change',function(){ 
   $("#"+id).css("font-family", $(this).val());
  });

Answer (score 1):

Use this, example:

```
$('some_element').click(function(){
    $('some_element').css({'font-size':'12px','font-family':'Arial'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to learn about is here - http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements=$("div.thisClass");
elements.each(function(i){
  $(this).css({'font-size':'3em', 'font-family':'Verdana'});  
 });
```

Comment: You can skip the `.each()` and just call `.css()` directly on the jQuery object.

Comment: true +1 for that. But .each could also be helpful if he/she wants to set different font styles and family on `each` element inside the div.